# PostgreSQL - Importando .CSV em uma tabela já existente

Tags: postgresql, csv, importação

Possuo uma tabela com três colunas, que já possui dados, em meu PostgreSQL.

Tenho um arquivo .CSV com quatro colunas.

Gostaria de adicionar os dados de três colunas do .CSV ao SQL sem substituir os que já estão lá.

Como fazer ?

```
SQL
Schema: cnpj
Table: cnae
Fields: cnpj, cnae, data

cnpj_dados_cnae_secundario_filt.CSV
Colunas: cnpj, cnae, nat_jur, data
```

- Ainda não tentei nada pois estou com medo de substituir os dados que já estão lá

Obrigado.

Comment: Explique em detalhes o significado de "sem substituir os que já estão lá". Qual a chave primária de sua tabela? Tem outros índices?

Comment: Não possui chave primária, apenas estes campos. "sem substituir os que já estão lá" quer dizer que a tabela já possui dados e quero acrescentar outros, mantendo os antigos.

Comment: Utilize o comando `COPY` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) especificando o parâmetro `FORMAT CSV`. Ele irá acrescentar os novos registros, oriundos do arquivo, à tabela. Parece que sua tabela contém um campo inexistente em seu arquivo csv, neste caso este campo ficará com NULL.

Comment: Seria algo tipo: COPY INTO cnpj_dados_cadastrais_pj.cnae
FROM 'G:\cnpj_dados_cnae_secundario_filt.csv'
WITH  
 ( 
 FIELDTERMINATOR =  '#',  
 FIRSTROW = 2,
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com o que você informou em sua pergunta:

1. Se o arquivo.csv estiver na máquina do servidor postgresql use o comando SQL:

   COPY cnpj.cnae(cnpj, cnae, nat_jur)
       FROM 'G:\cnpj_dados_cnae_secundario_filt.csv'
       WITH FORMAT CSV
       HEADER
       DELIMITER '#'
       FORCE_NULL (nat_jur);
2. Caso o arquivo resida numa máquina cliente utilize o `\copy` do `psql`.